# OpneCV webcam video capture Jupytor vs PyCharm

Tags: opencv, pycharm

I installed OpenCV 4 and copied a sample face detection from webcam tutorial to see if it works. The code worked fine at Jupytor Notebook. I used the exact same code in PyCharm but it behaved differently.

ret, frame = cv2.VideoCapture(0).read() # ret is True in Jupytor, but False in PyCharm

I tried to work with images using cv2.imread(), and the code worked fine in both. Is there a setting I need to enable for PyCharm to work with my laptop webcam?

Comment: Are you on macOS?

Comment: Yes; I am using MacOS

Comment: Then it is probably this known issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-219288